# Exporting does not match what I am viewing

Tags: export, 3d-printing

New to blender, I'm working on a big project and am really juggling learning multiple different programs to get what I need

If there is an easier way I am all ears. I'm piecing things together from random stuff on the internet.

Basically I created a drawing in a CAD program and am trying to make it a 3d object. I have tried dozens of conversions and multiple different programs. I finally thought I got the solution with Blender but when I export the object as either an stl or obj file it is janky as heck and I'm sure that is my fault but I need help fixing.

I imported the SVG into Blender, joined all the paths and then using the *Object Data* properties tab to extrude it to make it 3d. When that didn't output as i was viewing I tried googling solutions which lead me to try converting to a mesh, followed by adding a subdivision surface and triangulating it, which didn't fix it either.

Again, I don't really know what I'm doing, just trying what I find online, please don't just give me crap about anything I may be failing at.

I've attached picture that has: The original svg, the edited blender, and the exported stl

[image]

This is one of multiple files I'm trying to do this to so just recreating it, or drawing it in another program would be my last resort, please don't start with that.

Comment: In what way does the second picture not meet your needs?  That outcome is roughly what I'd expect from extruding an SVG.

Comment: @Kirbinator the images from left to right are 1) the original SVG, 2) the edited one in Blender, and 3) the exported STL. The 2) is fine. It's the last one, the exported model that has the problem. 2) and 3) should look the same.

Comment: @Wash Esler Have you scaled the object? Try to apply the scale (Ctrl+A, Scale). And maybe convert the edited object into a mesh first before you export it? (in Object mode, select menu *Object > Convert To > Mesh*). What does the exported object look like when you import it back into Blender?

Comment: @Blunder I have not tried scaling it bc the dimensions are set for very specific reasons. Would that actually make a difference though? I converted it to a mesh before adding the surface subdivision/triangles, are you saying try to mesh it again? When I import it back in it looks: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2gbg.png

But when I exported it a second time as an stl, it still looked like the original blocky mess

Comment: When the scale of the object is not 1.0 this can cause problems. But when you haven't scaled the object it should be fine. And just checking, no need to convert it to a mesh again when you already did that. Hmm, I don't know. If the mesh is ok then either Blender's export or the STL import is bad. Have you tried to import it to another program?